# Anything to recommend for a Linux newbie?

Tags: command-line

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and am wondering if there would be anything you guys could recommend me, be it a book, webseries or anything to learn about Linux and it's Command Line.

Comment: Not going to stay open for long since this is too broad a question. Use the internet, it is there for you in case you need answers.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I found that learning how to use the terminal (command line) to be one of the most important aspects of becoming more familiar with Linux.  Not only is it a powerful tool for getting stuff done, but it also forced me to learn more about Linux in general, prompting me to research new questions and ideas.  It was described to me as, "If you can't do it in the terminal, it cannot be done, period."

I used the following resource to get started learning how to use the terminal:

http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

In addition Codecademy has a section for learning how to use the terminal.

Here is my suggestion, from one beginner to another, the next time you want to do something on your computer, use Google and see how it's done from the terminal.  Practice creating new folders and moving and renaming files, try to compile a simple program from the source, learn how to use the terminal to play music, open images, format a flashdrive.  Read the man pages and become familiar reading those (so you get the hang of the syntax; commands, options, arguments).

In my opinion there is no better way to learn, than to be hands-on.  Have fun!